# How to link css to html with this pathway (image)

Tags: html, css, path

[Pathway image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdOja.png)

I would like to link style.css to my to my html page ATC1O.html. I added more periods after 'href="' but that is not working. Is there a way to link this at all?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
../../../css/style.css
```

./ represents current directory, so this is dance

../ represents the parent directory, so this will be art

../../ represents Parent's parent directory, so document

../../../ represents Parent's parent's parent directory, which you have not shown in the image, but it contains the "document" the "css" directory. So we go into it and then choose the /css/style.css file.

Hope It isn't confusing!

Answer (score 1):

Try "../../css/style.css" or "../../../css/style.css".

It's kind of hard to know how deep ATC10.html is from your image.  All I know is that its not the direct parent.

Comment: ../../../css/style.css worked thank you i was stuck on that for an hour. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
```

[more info here](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/)